# AngularJs routeProvider http status 403

Tags: javascript, security, http-status-code-403, angularjs-routing

I'm doing authentication and authorization in the server side.

In angularJs I'm doing the routing using the routeProvider like this.

```
$routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/_home',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        }).
        when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/_home',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        }).
        when('/users', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/_users',
            controller: 'UserCtrl'
        }).
        when('/users/:id', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/_userForm',
            controller: 'UserCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
```

And here is the problem to solve, when I get a 403 angular is not showing the server page, it just does not do nothing.

[image]

Did some one has a suggestion of how to handle this?

Comment: Error 403 „Execute access forbidden” – try to open URL `/test/partials/_userForm` – what you have in response? It has nothing in common with AngularJS, it is your server. What you expect from Angular if 403 happens? Redirect to some login page?

Comment: Yes it's the server response, what I want is to show the content of that 403 error page. but angular is not showing nothing when it gets that error.

Comment: You want to display this template or handle error 403?

Comment: The 403 error page that my server provide.

Comment: I am facing the same error, but I want to show the template, what is the best practice to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

### AngularJS Interceptors - updated to v1.4.2

> The interceptors are service factories that are registered with the $httpProvider by adding them to the $httpProvider.interceptors array. The factory is called and injected with dependencies (if specified) and returns the interceptor.

To read more: [$http angularjs Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

### Section config (part of it)

```
.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('responseObserver');
})
```

### Response - observer factory

`403.html` and `500.html` are existing HTML files, nice styled with some help content for user.

```
.factory('responseObserver', function responseObserver($q, $window) {
    return {
        'responseError': function(errorResponse) {
            switch (errorResponse.status) {
            case 403:
                $window.location = './403.html';
                break;
            case 500:
                $window.location = './500.html';
                break;
            }
            return $q.reject(errorResponse);
        }
    };
});
```

To extend knowledge about interceptors: http://djds4rce.wordpress.com/2013/08/13/understanding-angular-http-interceptors/

Comment: Don't you add `$window` as a dependency?  Otherwise, it works.

Comment: It works like a charm ! I use $location instead of $window