# How to configure Angular $resourceProvider for get method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, angular-resource

I am using `$resource` in Angular js. I want to configure `$resource` using `$resourceProvider` in such a way that I can handle the server response.

**For Example**

I am doing a `get` request for user profile and if I get `500` error from server I should give an `alert("Something went wrong at server");` and if I get `403` I should give `alert("You don't have permission to access this resource");` How can I achieve this?

I have done some other configuration like this:

```
$resourceProvider.defaults.actions.update = {
   method: 'PUT'
};
```

This works fine the same way I want to achieve this goal.

Thanks.

Comment: The `$resource` should not pop up alerts, that's a mixing of responsibilities that makes it a headache to reuse. A *controller* should be responsible for popping up visible alerts and such, not a backend service.

Comment: @_deceze_ Thanks, I very much agree with you. But I want a mechanism through which I can inform my service to show an `alert()`

Comment: Have a look at [the angular http docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: Instead of `resourceProvider` consider to use `$httpProvider` - like that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25041929/angularjs-routeprovider-http-status-403/25043231#25043231

Answer (score 0):

You should create a responseError interceptor to handle any type of error.

Here is plunker to demonstrate the use of interceptor.

https://plnkr.co/edit/4E2YAiwCOgA1Nw5d7CC2?p=preview

This will not give any error.

Go to resource.js file and change this line

`restPath = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes'`

to `restPath = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes1212'`

Now you will see an alert message for 404